# Sending wrong email template when case is closed

Tags: email-template, case, email2case, case-auto-response

I have assigned case close template in support settings and i have created auto response rule given rule entry when case status is closed send a case a closure email template.I am manually selecting in checkbox after the case is closed to notify a contact but no use .

Sending case creation template.

Please help .Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe autoresponse rules fire on Insert only.   You'll need to change this to a Workflow + Email Alert Action

Answer (score 2):

Auutoresponse rules fire on Insert only; similar to an email you receive when submitting information on a website.

To accomplish what you seek, you'll need to change this to a Workflow + Email Alert Action.   This Workflow should be setup so when you case is updated to contain values where IsClosed = TRUE (and any other criteria), it will fire off the email template you select in your email alert.

Since you are receiving the Case Creation template whe closing, I also recommend revising your existing case creation workflow rule to exclude closed cases after update.